# How to inherit from a regular matrix

Tags: julia

```
using ShiftedArrays

struct CircularMatrix{T} <: AbstractArray{T,2}
    data::Array{T,2}
    view::CircShiftedArray
    currentIndex::Int
    function CircularMatrix{T}(dims...) where T
        data = zeros(T, dims...)
        CircularMatrix(data, ShiftedArrays.circshift(data, (0, -1)), 1)
    end
end

Base.size(M::CircularMatrix) = size(M.data)
Base.eltype(::Type{CircularMatrix{T}}) where {T} = T

function shift_forward!(M::CircularMatrix)
    M.shift_forward!(1)
end

function shift_forward!(M::CircularMatrix, n)
    # replace the view with a view shifted forwards.
    M.currentIndex += n
    M.view = ShiftedArrays.circshift(M.data, (n, M.currentIndex))
end

@inline Base.@propagate_inbounds function Base.getindex(M::CircularMatrix, i) = M.view[i]
@inline Base.@propagate_inbounds function Base.setindex!(M::CircularMatrix, data, i) = M.view[i] = data
```

How can I make CircularMatrix act just like a regular matrix.
So that I can access it like

```
m = CircularMatrix{Int}(4,4)
m[1, 1] = 5
x = view(m, 1, :)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your matrix type is defined to be a subtype of `AbstractArray{T, 2}`. You need to implement a few methods in the informal array interface of Julia for your type to make functions and features that work on `AbstractArray{T, 2}` to also work on your custom type, that is, to make your `CircularMatrix` an iterable, indexable, completely functioning matrix.

The methods to implement are

1. `size(M::CircularMatrix)`
2. `getindex(M::CircularMatrix, i::Int)`
3. `getindex(M::CircularMatrix, I::Vararg{Int, N})`
4. `setindex!(M::CircularMatrix, v, i::Int)`
5. `setindex!(M::CircularMatrix, v, I::Vararg{Int, N})`

You already implement 1, 2 and 4 but have not yet set your indexing style. You might not need 3 and 5 if you choose [linear indexing style](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.IndexStyle). You only need to set `IndexStyle` to be `IndexLinear()` and maybe a few modifications, then everything should just work for your matrix.

### 1. `size(M::CircularMatrix)`

The first one is `size`. `size(A::CircularMatrix)` returns a `Tuple` of dimensions of `A`. I believe for your matrix probably something like the following

```
Base.size(M::CircularMatrix) = size(M.data)
```

### 2. `getindex(M::CircularMatrix, i::Int)`

This method is needed if you choose *linear indexing style*. `getindex(M, i::Int)` should give you the value at linear index `i`. You already implement it in your code. If you choose linear indexing, you need to set `IndexStyle` for your type and then you simply skip 3 and 5. Julia will automatically convert multiple index accesses, e.g. `a[3, 5]`, to a linear index access.

```
Base.IndexStyle(::Type{<:CircularMatrix}) = IndexLinear()

Base.@propogate_inbounds function Base.getindex(M::CircularMatrix, i::Int)
    @boundscheck checkbounds(M, i)
    @inbounds M.view[i]
end
```

It might be better to use `@inbounds` here on the second line. If the caller doesn't use `@inbounds`, we check the bounds first and this *hopefully* makes the subsequent bounds check unnecessary. You might want to omit this during development, though.

### 3. `getindex(M::CircularMatrix, I::Vararg{Int, N})`

The third one is for Cartesian indexing style. If you choose this style you need to implement this method. `Vararg{Int, N}` in the signature stands for "exactly `N` `Int` arguments". Here `N` should be equal to the dimensionality of `CircularMatrix`. Since this is a matrix, N should be two. If you choose this style, you need to define something like the following

```
Base.@propogate_inbounds function Base.getindex(A::CircularMatrix, I::Vararg{Int, 2})
    @boundscheck checkbounds(A, I...)
    @inbounds A.view[# convert I[1]` and `I[2]` to a linear index in `view`]
end
```

or since your dimensionality is not parametric and a matrix is 2D, simply

```
 Base.@propogate_inbounds function Base.getindex(A::CircularMatrix, i::Int, j::Int)
    @boundscheck checkbounds(A, i, j)
    @inbounds A.view[# convert i` and `j` to a linear index in `view`]
end
```

### 4. `setindex!(M::CircularMatrix, v, i::Int)`

The fourth one is similar to the second. This method should set the value at linear index `i`, if you choose linear indexing style.

### 5. `setindex!(M::CircularMatrix, v, I::Vararg{Int, N})`

The fifth one should be similar to the third, if you choose Cartesian indexing style.

---

After the implementations for 1, 2, and 4 and setting `IndexStyle`, you should have a custom matrix type that just works.

```
m[1, 1] = 5
x = view(m, 1, :)

for e in 
  ...
end

for i in eachindex(m)
  ...
end

display(m)
println(m)
length(m)
ndims(m)
map(f, A)
....
```

These should all work.

#### A few notes

- There is a documentation for Abstract Arrays interface [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array-1) with a few examples. You can also see *Optional Methods* to implement.
- There is a [JuliaArray](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/) organization on GitHub that provides lots of useful custom array implementations including `StaticArrays`, `OffsetArrays`, etc. and also a [JuliaMatrices](https://github.com/JuliaMatrices) organization that provides custom matrix types. You might want to take a look at their implementations.
- `@inline` is redundant if you use `Base.@propogate_inbounds`.

> @propagate_inbounds
>
> Tells the compiler to *inline* a function while retaining the caller's
>     inbounds context.

- You do not need to define `eltype` for your matrix, since there is already a definition for `AbstractArray{T, N}` which returns `T`.

Comment: Awesome answer dude. Thank you!